# Porque me detiene el sistema

Tags: asp.net, asp, visual, visual-basic

que tal amigos estoy trabajando con un sistema en visual basic asp.net estoy intentando cargar un gridview desde un archivo de excel utilizando este control ASPxUploadControl1 pero al yo ejecutar y precionar el boton ASPxUploadControl1 que dice examinar busca bien el archivo y justo despues me detiene la ejecucion y no se porque sucede eso espero puedan ayudarme

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el codigo:

```
   Protected Sub btnCargar_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles 
  btnCargar.Click

    If ASPxUploadControl1.UploadedFiles.Count > 0 Then
        Dim file As UploadedFile = ASPxUploadControl1.UploadedFiles(0)
        Dim dt As New DataTable

        Using mystream As Stream = file.FileContent
        Using myreader As IExcelDataReader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateOpenXmlReader(mystream)

        Dim conf = New ExcelDataSetConfiguration With {
            .ConfigureDataTable = Function(__) New ExcelDataTableConfiguration With {
            .UseHeaderRow = True
            }
        }

                dt = myreader.AsDataSet().Tables(0)
         End Using
         End Using

        GridView1.DataSource = dt
        GridView1.DataBind()
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Por qué mejor también no pones el código de lo que tienes en la imagen?

Comment: Listo ya lo añadi

Comment: Que añadiste???

Comment: Ese es el codigo que tengo en la imagen, pero tambien intente con otros codigo donde el ASPxUploadControl tiene un evento que se dispara al cargar el excel y aun asi en cuanto lo busca lo carga detiene la ejecucion